# Tkinter Buttons passing function on initialisation rather than on click

Tags: tkinter

Sorry if this is a weirdly written question, i'm not usually one to ask them.
I was working on a project to pass time while I am out of college and I thought it would be fun to put together a basic role-playing game. I decided to work on the battle system before I made anything for the over-world. Until yesterday I had no problems getting tkinter to run correctly and then, when I reorganised the code that I had written, my buttons started firing their commands when I declared them and stopped doing so when they are clicked. I went online looking for answers to my problem. When none of them worked, I threw together a basic version of the system I am using and I came here.

```
try:
    from tkinter import *
except:
    from Tkinter import *

master = Tk()

def callback():
    print("click!")

Button_Fight = Button(master, text="  Fight  ", command=callback(), height=4, width=24, font='Arial', state = DISABLED)

Button_Run = Button(master, text="   Run   ", command=callback(), height=4, width=24, font='Arial', state = DISABLED)



Button_Fight["state"] = NORMAL
Button_Fight.grid(column=1, row=1)

Button_Run["state"] = NORMAL
Button_Run.grid(column=2, row=2)

master.mainloop()
```

Any help at all would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Please do not edit the title of the question to indicate that your question has been answered. Mark one answer that solved your question as "accepted" by clicking the check icon instead.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your issue is that when you call a function in a tkinter object you don't put the parentheses. so for example replace this line of code:

```
command=callback(),
```

with this line:

```
command=callback,
```

This will make it so it calls the function when clicked rather than when you run the program.